# Настройка .htaccess для локального сайта

Tags: .htaccess, url, modx

Создаю сайт локально. Но что-то с адресами: открывается только главная страница (она же пока и 404) - что из браузера, что по ссылке на странице.

Использую MODX. Дружественные URL включил, вложенные - пока выключил. В index.html использую тег:

```
<base href="[[!++site_url]]" />
```

В .htaccess пока ничего не трогал. Подскажите, что делать?

Comment: `.htaccess` переименовал правильно? как именно локально сайт развернут? `!` в `[[!++site_url]]` лишний - это системная настройка.

Comment: 1) Просто во FreeCommander взял и переименовал.

Comment: 2) Поставил MODX в OpenServer/domains/mysite/, создал БД, пользователя и т.д. согласно онлайн уроку. В /assets/templates/ кинул парочку страниц и css. Настроил кое-что в админке (в т.ч. дружественные URL) - также согласно онлайн уроку.

Answer (score 0):

Если все страницы кроме главной выдают 404 - дело в htaccess - ищи в чем дело в нем. Может имя не так, может апач настроен неправильно. Либо выключи дружественные урлы вообще - для теста локального будет достаточно и работать всё будет в обход htaccess.

Comment: Выключил дружественные URL - страница открывается. Но мне-то так неудобно работать... Как на сайте прописывать ссылки?

Comment: Ничего не поделать - либо разбираться в чем дело - либо так. Ссылки указываются вот так: `[[~нужный_айди_ресурса]]`

Comment: Ладно, спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 0):

Раскомментируйте в файле .htaccess (снимите #) следующие строчки:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Затем для сайта без www раскомментируйте:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example-domain-please-change\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://example-domain-please-change.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Если сайт с www, то эти:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example-domain-please-change\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example-domain-please-change.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Не забудьте заменить тут адрес на свой, и не используйте оба этих варианта одновременно!
Должно сработать